# Why does vvvv need winlock?

Tags: windows

I was trying to get vvvv (vvvv.org) so I could use it and make awesome videos, but when I started to extract McAfee warned me about a PUP (potentially unwanted program) called WinLockDLL.dll. Now, I googled this, and while it seems to be a parental/administrative control program to limit certain features of a computer to monitor use, it also seems to be commonly used as a virus. The thing that boggles me is how it is proprietary software, yet some viruses package it?

Now, this brings me to my main point: Why on earth does vvvv need it, and why don't we have to pay for it when it comes with this? Is it unwanted, forced into the .zip by a hacker, or is it actually part of vvvv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need it, just delete it.

It's used by certain features to disable control of standard OS shortcuts.  Ideal when you have an install you don't want tampered with.  It's totally safe, but obviously the calls it makes match patterns used in virus' to do exactly the same thing.